# Accessing global variables within ipython

Tags: python, ipython, global

In `ipython` I am using `%run` to execute the following code from a file:

```
foo = 32

def test7():
    global foo
    print("foo before:", foo)
    foo += 1
    print("foo after:", foo)
```

My `ipython` transcript goes as follows:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) ...

In [1]: %run "a1.py"

In [2]: foo
Out[2]: 32

In [3]: test7()
foo before: 32
foo after: 33

In [4]: foo
Out[4]: 32

In [5]: test7()
foo before: 33
foo after: 34

In [6]: foo
Out[6]: 32

In [7]:
```

My question is: why does querying the value of `foo` within `ipython` always return 32 when the `test7()` routine seems to be incrementing it?

And is there a way I can see the same value of `foo` that the `test7()` function is seeing?

Comment: hi there! i tried running this in google collab with the following code after your snippet to  try to replicate your problem but i dont get any such issues. `print(foo) test7() print(foo) test7() print(foo)` (All are in new lines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `%run` the [`-i` flag](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) to "run the file in IPython’s namespace instead of an empty one."

```
In [1]: %run -i "a1.py"

In [2]: foo
Out[2]: 32

In [3]: test7()
foo before: 32
foo after: 33

In [4]: foo
Out[4]: 33

In [5]: test7()
foo before: 33
foo after: 34

In [6]: foo
Out[6]: 34
```

I find the docs a little confusing, but I think they are trying to explain the behavior with:

> The file is executed in a namespace initially consisting only of `__name__=='__main__'` and sys.argv constructed as indicated. It thus sees its environment as if it were being run as a stand-alone program (except for sharing global objects such as previously imported modules). But **after execution, the IPython interactive namespace gets updated with all variables defined in the program** (except for `__name__` and `sys.argv`).

Also worth noting is this from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

> Programmer’s note: global is a directive to the parser. It applies only to code parsed at the same time as the global statement. In particular, a global statement contained in a string or code object supplied to the built-in exec() function does not affect the code block containing the function call, and code contained in such a string is unaffected by global statements in the code containing the function call.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `foo` is always 32 is because `foo` variable is stored in an specific memory space and if you don't pass `-i` as @Mark mentions it will return the value stored in that specific memory space:

```
In [1]: %run "a1.py"

In [2]: foo
Out[2]: 32

In [3]: id(foo)
Out[3]: 1543004777744

In [4]: id(32)
Out[4]: 1543004777744

In [5]: test7()
foo before: 32
foo after: 33

In [6]: id(foo)
Out[6]: 1543004777744

In [7]: id(33)
Out[7]: 1543004777776
```

You can notice `32` constant and `foo` variable have the same `ID` value